# How to get all the data from a website who are using a google map plugin?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to get all the hospitals listed here in this website together with their other information. It is a website that uses a google map plug-in:

http://www.maps.doh.gov.ph/facilities.html

is there a some kind of software that can crawl all the information I need? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its the Data you are after just open up the Network tab of your Browser Dev tools, the Data is coming from the network requests of the form:

values?alt=json-in-script&callback=displayPointsNew&t=1441938811445

i.e:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1hcS-OTajzxhLSoGhpVLyxaHNArA8cPdk2Ks6hELKl9E/od9/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=displayPointsNew&t=1441938811445